# Simple Similarity Questions

Tags: geometry

If I know the four pairs of corresponding angles in two quadrilateral are congruent, does it follow that the quadrilaterals are similar? Please explain why as well.

Thanks

Comment: Are they in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

No, the special case of rectangulars does not necessarily give similar figures.