# Quadrilateral Similarity Question

Tags: geometry

> Are all quadrilaterals with congruent angles, corresponding angles similar? Why?

*Note:* Rectangles won't be taken into consideration

Comment: Are all rectangles similar?

Comment: @CYAries No, but is this true for other quadrilaterals?

Comment: How about parallelograms with angles $60^\circ$ and $120^\circ$?

Comment: You asked this same question an hour ago. Please delete that one, since thos one has several answers. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214566/simple-similarity-questions

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would say no. Consider, for instance, a parallelogram. What happens when we extend equally the parallel sides? Stay angles the same? Are the resulting parallelograms similar?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the four angles the assertion is false. To see why, draw one quadrangle with those angles. Now pick any side and slide the line it's on parallel to itself and construct a new quadrangle with a side on the new line. At least two of the side lengths will have changed, and at least one will be the same, so the new quadrangle is not similar to the original.